# Cannot match string with optional whitespace using regex

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to match the following strings:
`/*virtual*/`, `/* virtual*/`, `/*virtual */` and `/* virtual */`

The regexp `/\*\svirtual\s\*/` correctly matches the version with two spaces, however replacing `\s` by `[\s]*` does not match any of these strings... From reading the emacs [RegularExpression](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) reference document on the wiki I have assumed that this should create a regex matching my specification. I am still a bit new to regular expressions, any help (and explanation why the above is faulty) is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `re-builder`. It's so useful.
And the expression is

```
"/\\* ?virtual ?\\*/"
```

Or, if you like to go with `s-`,

```
"/\\*\\s-?virtual\\s-?\\*/"
```

But note that it's not exactly a space, but whatever the syntax
defines to be whitespace. So I could write a mode that designates
all words `like` as whitespace, and your regex would match them.

Comment: Yes indeed, very useful! However, it turns out, it wasn't really my regex that was faulty but rather that I use then inside the function `(s-contains? "REGEX" (buffer-substring beg-of-line end-of-line))` where the variables are the beginning/end of the current line. This does not support regular expressions. I will accept your answer because of the suggestion of `re-builder` and because of pointing out the problem with the whitespace class.

Comment: Btw, I usually prefer `buffer-substring-no-properties`. Not sure if it's faster, but it probably is. And more readable when debugging.

Comment: Just a note, if you prefer the expression to match only a single space instead of any whitespace (tab), use `[C-q SPC]` instead of `[\s-]`.

Comment: abo-abo: `[\s-]` matches any of backslash, lower-case s, or hyphen. I don't think you wanted any square brackets there.

Comment: @phis, actually it was because of `re-builder`. It actually thinks that [\s-] matches a space.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an emacs bug?

```
\*[\s]*virtual[\s]*\*
```

works in JS, see http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ (check 'global')

Comment: Emacs has a different regex syntax